# Cannot read request body even though the http request succesfull

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to send a piece of data to the nodejs server from my react application using Axios. Here is my react and nodejs code

```
const candidates = ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Bob Smith'];
   
const writeFileApi = axios.create({
            method: 'post',
            baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: { candidates1: candidates }
          });
        
        writeFileApi.post('/')
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
```

and my nodejs code.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("hello world");
  console.log(req.body); // this should log the data sent in the request body
  res.send('Data received successfully');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Even though my nodejs terminal successfully prints the hello world. I cannot read the **candidates1** array from the **req.body**. Initially, my application was much more complex and I simplified to this I can still not get the array. Why cant I read the array even though the request is successful.

Comment: Just a tip, you do NOT need to install and import body-parser manually if you're using Express 4.16+. Body-parser is included in the express package from this version. You can use app.use(express.json()); to parse JSON bodies and app.use(express.urlencoded()); to parse URL-encoded bodies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of your request should be included as the second parameter to `writeFileApi.post`, e.g.

```js
writeFileApi.post('/', {
  candidates: ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Bob Smith']
))
```

as per: https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example